# Proper way to use python's datetime's strftime method

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, fuse, strftime

I am using FUSE (a virtual file system) to try and implement a read call that will give me the current date/time as a string.

```
import os
import sys
import errno

import datetime

from fuse import FUSE, FuseOSError, Operations

class FileSys(Operations):

    def __init__(self, root):
            self.root = root

    def _full_path(self, partial):
            if partial.startswith("/"):
                    partial = partial[1:]
            path = os.path.join(self.root, partial)
            return path

    # allows us to set attributes
    def getattr(self, path, fh= None):
            full_path = self._full_path(path)
            st = os.lstat(full_path)
            return dict((key, getattr(st, key)) for key in ('st_atime', 'st_ctime',
                 'st_gid', 'st_mode', 'st_mtime', 'st_nlink', 'st_size', 'st_uid'))

    # allows us to see files
    def readdir(self, path, fh):

            #logging.info("Enter readdir")
            full_path = self._full_path(path)
            dirents = ['.', '..']
            if(os.path.isdir(full_path)):
                    dirents.extend(os.listdir(full_path))

            for r in dirents:
                yield r

    def read(self, path, length, offset, fh= None):

        date = datetime.datetime.today()
        date = date.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
        return date

def main(root, mountpoint):

    FUSE(FileSys(root), mountpoint, foreground= True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main('/home/user/mydir', '/mnt/dummy')
```

However, my output is printing like this

```
Tue May 2
```

When I really want something like this

```
Tue May 27 14:43:06 CDT 2014
```

So, only getting up to the first digit of the day. Anyone see what I am doing wrong? I looked at the strftime documentation and I am sure all of my letters are corresponding to the correct pieces of the formatted string.

Comment: Your code works for me ... are you sure that's exactly the code that's causing you problems?

Comment: I am also using FUSE, so this is the return call from a virtual filesystem's 'read' method.

Comment: @Zack: then *show us that code*; your assessment of the problem is incorrect. The code posted works, it is a problem with your FUSE setup instead.

Comment: And how are you reading your virtual file?

Comment: @MartijinPieters : 'cat today.txt'

Comment: Should have specified if it isn't obvious, I run this script, then cd into the '/mnt/dummy' directory and then cat 'today.txt'

Comment: One more, maybe obvious thing.. today.txt is a file inside '/home/user/mydir', I am attempting to override the normal cat function call with one that will display the date.

Comment: @Zack: perhaps you want to heed the `length` and `offset` parameters: `return date[offset:offset + length]`. I suspect that FUSE might not like it when you return more data than `length` specified.

Comment: Also, what is the real size of `today.txt`? Perhaps FUSE thinks it only has a file size of 9.

Comment: today.txt is a simple 'hello world' line. I'll try your first suggestion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the size of my file was the problem. I threw a bunch of placeholder lines into today.txt and that did the trick.